# Returning realtime database data in http trigger in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an API in firebase where it takes latitude, longitude parameter and query the realtime database and returns data fetched as the API response. But it returns firebase promise which works async . How make it blocking ??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: welcome to SO, please share your code, we cannot guess how you implement your functions

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it blocking -- JavaScript is non-optionally non-blocking. What you can do it wait until it completes to respond:

```
exports.myFn = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  admin.database().ref('some/path').once('value').then(snap => {
    res.json(snap.val());
  }, err => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Unexpected error.');
  });
});
```